# Automatically copy rows into separate worksheet when column is blank (to track accounts receivable)

Tags: excel, vba

We have a workbook called Shipsheet, and in that workbook we have a worksheet called "SHIPSHEET 2015" where we keep track of all our invoices.  For invoices that have not been paid (invoices for which there is no "X" in the paid column (column H)), we  manually add the invoice to a separate worksheet in the same workbook called "Cash Flow", which is chronological.  In other words, the invoices that are the longest overdue show up at the top of the Cash Flow worksheet.  I also note that we have different terms for different customers, which we keep track of in column G of SHIPSHEET 2015:  "net 10", "net 30" or "due on receipt".

I would like to have Cash Flow automatically populated from SHIPSHEET 2015. And I would like Cash Flow to be automatically sorted with the longest past due invoice on top.

I have searched many of the threads here that show various ways to create code that will copy rows to another worksheet if certain conditions are met, but I have not had any luck in getting them to work.

My parameters are:

- If column H in SHIPSHEET 2015 is blank, then copy that row to the Cash Flow worksheet.  Ideally, I would just like to copy columns A, C, G, M and N to the Cash Flow worksheet as the other are not needed.
- due date of the invoice depends on the date of the invoice (which is in column B of SHIPSHEET 2015) and terms in column G.  So an invoice dated 11-15-2015 with net 10 terms is due on 11-25-2015.   As mentioned above, I would like Cash Flow to be automatically sorted with the longest past due invoice on the top.

Here is what I tried just to get started, before trying the sorting and copying of just specific cells in the rows.

Sub copyrows()

```
Dim tfCol As Range, Cell As Object

Set tfCol = Range("A5000:A6000")

For Each Cell In tfCol

    If IsEmpty(Cell) Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Copy
        Sheet2.Select
        ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    End If

    If Cell.Value = "X" Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  SO is not a code for me site but a very helpful tool in finding and overcoming errors.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be making progress with a loop that examines each row (and optionally copies it) individually but I would like to see you consider an [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx). This is a bulk operation that is typically quicker than a loop through each row.

```
Sub Ship_to_CashFlow()
    Dim wsCF As Worksheet

    'set the receiving worksheet
    Set wsCF = Worksheets("Cash Flow")

    With Worksheets("SHIPSHEET 2015")
        'if the worksheet has a filter active, turn it off
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        'use the region specified by selecting A1 and tapping Ctrl+A once
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'filter for blanks in the 8th column (H)
            .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:="="
            'move down one row to discard the header row
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)
                'Are there any visible cells?
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Cells)) Then
                    'copy them to to the next blank row in the CF worksheet
                    .Copy Destination:=wsCF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            End With
            'turn off the filter
            .AutoFilter field:=8
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

That works on the area of data defined by the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx). A series of [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) isolate the area of the worksheet being examined and processed.

The sorting will likely require some sort of 'helper' column that will provide a number with a formula involving the invoice date column B and the terms from column G.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...I got a bit lost in your filter suggestion, and I got this to work instead:

```
Sub cond_copy()
    Sheets("2015 SHIPSHEET").Select
    RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Rng = Selection
    For i = 1 To RowCount
        Range("h" & i).Select
        check_value = ActiveCell
        If check_value = "" Or check_value = "" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("Sheet1").Select
            RowCount = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
            Range("a" & RowCount + 1).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("2015 SHIPSHEET").Select
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

But now instead of running this on the entire 2015 SHIPSHEET, I'd prefer to run it just on selected rows.  I tried adding

```
Set Rng = Selection
```

but that didn't work, it still ran it on the entire sheet.  Any suggest on how to just run this on selected rows?